# There is some simple refutation of scientism?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

Scientism (*Science as Ideology*) is the thesis that claims that the emphirical science is at least the best source of knowledge.
Two of the most important classifications of scientism are:

1. Strong scientism, that claims empirical science as the only source of knowledge.
2. Weak Scientism, that claim empirical science as the best source of knowledge.

I am being unable to find a clear and straigthforward refutation of this branch of scientism.

**Q**: So there is some clear and strightfoward refutaion of weak scientism?

Comment: What are strong and weak scientism ?

Comment: If you knwo about scientism you shloud know, but strong scientism affirms that the science is the only source of knowledge and weak scienticism affirms that science is the superior source of knowledge.

Comment: Nobody can guess if you are referring to well established terms or something you came up with on your own. The more precise (and properly spelled...) your question is, the higher the probability that you will get an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: Even strong scientism taken aspirationally (all truthful claims will likely be eventually validated by science, or something like that) is not self refuting, it is similar to more careful phrasings of radical skepticism, that likewise are not. As for weak scientism, what is "best" or "superior" is in the eye of the beholder, such value judgments are not subject to "refutation" at all. See [Hietanen et al., How Not to Criticise Scientism](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/meta.12443) on directions that plausible critique of scientisim can and cannot take.

Comment: @Conifold There is a great motivation to refutate weak scientism by my part, because is virtually the only arguemt used to attack the Austrian School of Economy from Ortodox Economists, and I am trying to defend it.

Comment: I understand, but refutation is a wrong goal here. Philosophy is not physics or mathematics, philosophical positions can be defended or undermined, but minimally careful ones cannot proved or refuted. See, for example, [Brown's critique](https://social-epistemology.com/2017/07/31/some-objections-to-moti-mizrahis-whats-so-bad-about-scientism-christopher-m-brown/) of Mizrahi's defense of weak scientism and [Mizrahi's response](https://social-epistemology.com/2018/04/10/more-in-defense-of-weak-scientism-moti-mizrahi/).

Comment: @Conifold I was thinking, I concluded that I just neded refutate weak scientism as more than a subjective thesis. Just prove that is no more than a opinion.

Comment: Science motivated opinions are backed by success of science, and scientism is not needed to criticize Mises's apriorism, so that will not be enough. For a recent defense of Austrian praxeology against orthodox criticisms see e.g. [Linsbichler, Austrian economics without extreme apriorism](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-019-02150-8)

Comment: @Conifold Is true that scientism is no needed to critisize Mises, Aporist but justifing the bases premises of the Austrian School is no left forgeted in my Agenda. PS. Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe there is none...

Answer (score 1):

'Best' is a value judgement, and science is not geared to give knowledge about human values. If you ask on what 'scientific' grounds they have determined that science is the 'best' source of knowledge, you'll get:

- incoherent ramblings or elliptical logic
- overt statements of belief
- scoffs, sneers, or snide remarks

What you will *not* get (In my experience) is anything resembling scientific analysis or evidence. If someone proves to be a tough nut to crack this way, ask more pointed questions:

- Is science the best source of knowledge for relationship or marital problems, and if so how?
- Is science the best source of knowledge for ending human warfare, and if so how?
- Is science the best source of knowledge about art, music, or other matters of aesthetics, and if so how?

Scientismists (Hey! You think of a better word!) are like all 'ismists' convinced that their ***beliefs*** about the world are instead ***inviolable facts*** about the world. Getting people to de-factualize their beliefs is always a tricky proposition; it cannot be done strictly through logic or reason, but needs more of a Socratic approach. And we all remember what happened to Socrates...

Comment: [Erdel von Mises], can you elaborate on what you mean by "empirical science"? Does this include one's experience of one's own sensory data and emotions?

Comment: I'd really like to know what's your definition of science, because according to the one I apply the answer to the last 3 question would be yes, yes and yes. And what would make the socratic approach not logical? That's one of the best logical masterpieces of human's history

Comment: @FabioR.:Science is a framework for methodologies that evaluate theoretical assumptions about the material ('natural') world. Scientific reasoning asks that generalized assertions about phenomena conform to practical, observable manifestations of those phenomena.

Comment: @FabioR.:Notice that while you answered 'yes' to the three questions I asked, you neglected to address the 'if so how?' part. That is a statement of faith, nothing more. I mean, if I asked if *God* was the best source of knowledge (BSoK), or *magic*, or *Elmo* (from Sesame Street), someone could sat 'yes' to any of those across the board. Saying 'yes' is easy, and often heartfelt. But trying to answer *how* Elmo is the BSoK for ending human warfare would give even the most diehard Elmo fan pause.

Comment: @FabioR.: As I often like to say, science can tell us that we can split atoms, and over time it can tell us how to do it more productively and efficiently. But science cannot tell us whether we should build nuclear bombs or nuclear power plants. Science is teleological, not moral. It can tell us how to achieve whatever goals we set, but it cannot tell us whether those goals are worth spit.

Comment: Yes obviously a full argument should have addressed those parts of the questions too, but that would require much more space than comments allow. I was not really after denying what you were saying it was more an attempt to understand what meaning of science is required to answer no to those questions as I would, according to the definition I've always applied, answer yes to all three of them (in short i think that even if humans are different the way they think and behave can be categorized and even predicted using the scientific method (as we already did for many things))

Comment: I was trying to answer your last argument but after a couple of tries I think there might have been a bit of a strawman here: never argued that science has to be used as a moral compass, science is a tool, science can help us achieve the goals we set, but it's us that have to set those goals. Once you set your goal then science can bring you there. You can set your goal with everything you want, but without science you get nowhere (or at least, you don't know if you did)